# DotNetOpenAuth and Quickbooks

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth, quickbooks

I'm need to develop a .NET 3.5 application that imports data from Quickbooks, and I decided to use DNOA to OAuthorize with them. I downloaded the latest available version (4.1.something), took a look around, then create a QuickBooksConsumer following the example of GoogleConsumer. However, there is a problem I cannot seem to solve.

The url of the QuickBooks REST services looks like this:

```
https://services.intuit.com/sb/{0}/v2/{1}
```

where:

`{0}` is the name of the object to get the records of (like, "invoice", or "payment");

`{1}` is the `realmId`, i.e. the id of the Company the data is required for

The problem is that I don't see how to do `PrepareAuthorizedRequest` with such variable urls. The function is not virtual, so I cannot override it in my `QuickBooksConsumer.cs`. I'm stuck.
Can you please show me the way how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Authorizing requests to dynamically created URLs should be no problem at all.  Just wrap any URL in a `MessageReceivingEndpoint` and send it through `ConsumerBase.PrepareAuthorizedRequest` and you're good to go.